# Polygon function

Tags: common-lisp

I need a little help. I'm stuck on one function which I need to make.

New polygon is made with function `make-polygon` without parameters and returns empty list of points. 
You can determine and change list of points by functions `items` and `set-items` . I can't figure out how to write `set-items` which should have two parameters (polygon and list of points) and returns polygon (list of points in form `((1 1) (2 1) (5 2) :black))` or similar ). It needs to be done with `make-point`.

```
"POINT"
(defvar *point*)
(defun make-point ()
  (setf *point* (list (list 0 0) :black)))
(defun x (point)
  (caar point))
(defun y (point)
  (cadar point))
(defun set-x (point new-x)
  (setf (caar point) new-x) #| musi byt x point |#
  point)
(defun set-y (point new-y)
  (setf (cadar point) new-y) #| musi byt y point |#
  point)
"POLYGON"
(defvar *polygon*)
(defun make-polygon () 
   (setf *polygon* (list nil :black))) 
(defun items (polygon) 
   (car polygon))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define it similarly to the `set-x`, `set-y` functions:

```
(defun set-items (polygon list-of-points)
  (setf (car polygon) list-of-points))
```

Note that this returns the list of points. If it should return the polygon the it could be modified as follows:

```
(defun set-items (polygon list-of-points)
  (setf (car polygon) list-of-points)
  polygon)
```

Let’s try if it works:

```
(let ((p1 (make-point))
      (p2 (make-point))
      (p3 (make-point))
      (poly (make-polygon)))
  (set-x p1 1)
  (set-y p1 1)
  (set-x p2 2)
  (set-y p2 1)
  (set-x p3 5)
  (set-y p3 2)
  (set-items poly (list p1 p2 p3))
  (loop for p in (items poly)
    do (format t "(~a, ~a) ~%" (x p) (y p))))
(1, 1) 
(2, 1) 
(5, 2) 
NIL
```

Comment: thanks , I wrote it like this on the first time but I thought it's to easy to be true :D